# What do we call an instance of a class in Java

Tags: java, class, instance

A question from my homework assignment asks

> What do we call an instance of a class in Java?

The choices are:

A. method
B. Package
C. Object
D. Variable

I think it's a variable because an instance is another word for an object, and objects have variables. Is my answer correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct. What's your 2nd choice? The question really is "what's another word that means the same thing as 'instance'"?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html

Comment: Why not `Object`, *since* "an *instance* is another word for an *object*"?

Answer (score 3):

The definition of an object in object oriented programming is an instance of a class. So the answer should be C. Object.

A variable is any reference that doesn't necessarily have to be an instance of a class. It could be a primitive type, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The answer would be Object. For me it's useful to think that a class is like a very general concept of something (e.g. the concept of a car) and the instance of a class is like the materialization of it, the "objectification" (a pick-up, a coupé, etc.).

Comment: A pick-up or a coupé is still a class. "The car I own" or "the car with license plate XYZ-123" is an example of an instance.

Comment: @Erwin Why wouldn't pick-up or coupé be objects?

Comment: There is more than one pick-up or coupé car in existence - they are a class of cars. (A subclass, in Java terms) An object is a specific instance of something, so that would be a specific car, which could be a pick-up, coupé or a general car.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` is an instance of `Class`.

`Class` defines a group of `Objects` with state (data) and behaviour (methods to act on data)

From your options, `method` has been ruled out as methods are defined in class and belong to objects.

`Variable` can be anything : primitive types like int, boolean etc or `Object` of any `Class` type like Thread etc.

You can think class as logical entity and object as physical entity.

Man can be a class with attributes like name,age etc with methods like `canWalk () and canThink ()`.

`Object` can be particular `instance` of `Man` with attribute values like Ravindra as name, 40 as age.

sample code:

```
public class Man{
    String name;
    int age;

    public Man(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void canWalk(){
        System.out.println("Can walk");
    }
    public void canThink(){
        System.out.println("Can think");
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Man:"+this.name+":"+age;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Man m1 = new Man("Ravindra", 40);
        Man m2 = new Man("Someoneelse",30);
        System.out.println(m1);
        System.out.println(m2);

    }
}
```

both m1 and m2 are `objects`, which are `instances` of `class` Man and they are different.